# No POST on new built desktop

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, power-supply, post

I just finished building a desktop again and it will not perform a successful POST. No beeps or video either.
Since my goal is a successful POST, i removed all irrelevant hardware already and am only going to list those parts being connected together:

Mobo: ASrock Extreme 3 Z170 (No LEDs at all on it)

RAM: 1 module Kingston 8GB 2133 MHz CL14 in slot with priority 1 according to mobo manual

CPU: i5 6600K tray/oem

PSU: Corsair Professional Series HX750W

Cooler: Noctua NH-U12P SE2 both fans connected to mobo

No other devices/peripherals connected.

The PSU is working for sure. Have had it powering another desktop before and tested it successful again after noticing that the new desktop won't POST.

So what is actually happening:
After pressing the power switch, PSU and CPU fans begin to spin, the LED on the case front is light up and thats it. It will stay in this state forever. No video, no beep.

I'm pretty sure the RAM works since there are indeed 3 beeps when there is no memory module installed, meaning the mobo notices the RAM module once it's installed.
Since there is no more beeps after the RAM module is installed, I'm guessing the CPU is working fine as well. Correct me if I'm wrong.

The fact that the fans are spinning and the speaker can actually beep means the mobo isn't as much broken as i first thought, but it is still very likely that it's the faulty part.

8 pin CPU power connector is connected as well as the 24 pin on the mobo.
CMOS reset was without success.

I have built several desktops before which are all working fine. Just 2 weeks ago I finished one with the exact same components but the mobo being a MSI z170 PC MATE. Worked like a charm.

Please help me

Comment: Have you double checked if there is any loose connections with any of the modules that you might of missed out when you installed it?